# What is the inverse notion of "refinement"

Tags: terminology, generic-programming

In the world of *generic programing* the notion of **refinement** is very common. In particular given a concept `C1`, then we say that a concept `C2` refines `C1` if it provides all the functionalities of `C1` and possibly more.

How do you call the inverse relation? So if `C2` is a refinement of `C1` then `C1` is a what of `C2`?

Comment: I encountered the term in a bit different context. Nevertheless, freely coined: _abstraction_.

Comment: @JoopEggen nice try. I think you are right *conceptually* :) There is another possibility - `C1` is generalization of `C2`.
So we have: *abstraction*, *lifting*, *generalization*.

Answer (score 1):

There are two terms in linguistics which define the relation discussed in the topic.

> **Hyponym** shares a type-of relationship with its **hypernym**.
>
> **Hypernymy** is the semantic relation in which one word is the hypernym of another. **Hyponymy** is the oppopsite relation.

Then "bulldog" is a *hyponym* of the "dog" concept, the "dog" concept is the *hypernym* for the *bulldog* concept.

Answer (score 0):

Since the related transformation of requirements is called "lifting" I suggest the same for concepts. `C1` is a lifting of `C2`. However someone with native English should better help here.

Comment: I'd say it not a question of english, rather of the standard terminology - in case there exists one...

Comment: Well, even if there is no standard term one can just name it properly.

Comment: I have asked this question here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113135/inverse-for-the-term-refinement