# What is a Scala refinement?

Tags: scala

A simple one for the weekend. There's little if any documentation on what this actually is, probably stashed in the language spec. Should be simple though - what is a "refinement" in scala?

Here's some code far from tantalizing:

```
class Foo[T, A <: SomeType](
  val io: Serializer[T, A] with Deserializer[T, A],
)
```

Coercing the compiler a little I gather that `io` is a refinement of `Serializer[T,A]` with `Deserializer[T,A]`. Cool. When can this be used in general, in scala? what are the rules? is any use of `with`, actually technically a refinement?

[P.S. here's something general about the term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355303/what-is-the-inverse-notion-of-refinement)

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't a refinement, it's a compound type without a refinement. See http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-types.html#compound-types for details:

> A compound type `T_1 with … with T_n { R }` represents objects with members as given in the component types `T_1`, …, `T_n` and the refinement `{ R }`.

Comment: Thanks for the link, which discusses refinements. This likely clears up the general aspect of the question. The specific case at hand is less interesting now..

Answer (score 1):

`Serializer` is a class and `Deserializer` is a [trait](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/trait/info). With the construct `Serializer[T, A] with Deserializer[T, A]` you basically create a new class (without a proper name) which inherits from `Sericalizer` and from `Deserializer`. Note that in Scala you can inherit from one class and an arbitrary number of traits.

Since this is inheritance at work, yes this is a refinement.

Comment: "Since this is inheritance at work, yes this is a refinement." No, it isn't (according to Scala specification). See http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-types.html#compound-types.

Comment: The 2.11 compiler says there is a refinement at that line, as per looking directly at the compiler symbol information obtained right after the `typer` phase of compilation.

Comment: As the link mentions, there is an empty refinement added implicitly. Perhaps that's what the compiler refers to?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov wasn't aware that the specs actually use the refinement and interpreted it in the general sense. Interesting.